# Fastlane Android Build in flutter issue

Tags: android, fastlane

When I take to build for the flutter app using Fastlane, the APK is being generated in a build folder outside the android folder.

The message after the successful build of android is

> *Couldn't find any new signed apk files...*

The generated paths are all empty.

[image: Generated paths]

But I found a generated APK outside the android folder in the path

> **build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk**

Will be the generated APK path be constant or will change with the future releases of flutter?
How to solve this issue?

Also, the GitHub issue for the same has been closed due to lack of inactivity.
ref: [github](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15278)

Comment: Did you get a solution ?

Comment: No. I had to take the file from the generated build folder.

Comment: @SanjeevS DId you found any solution or workaround for the same?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, I resolved by changing the configuration like below:

```
platform :android do
    desc ""
    lane :distribute do
    gradle(
        task: 'assemble',
        build_type: 'Release'
    )
        firebase_app_distribution(
            app: "<Enter your appId>",
            firebase_cli_token: "<Enter your token>",
            testers: "",
            release_notes: "",
            firebase_cli_path: "/usr/local/bin/firebase",
            apk_path: "../build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"
        )
    end
end
```

Run below fastlane commands:

```
fastlane add_plugin firebase_app_distribution
```

```
fastlane run firebase_app_distribution_login
```

The above command will provide you firebase_cli_token add the same to above configuration.

```
fastlane distribute
```

**Note: Make sure you login to your Firebase account and click on get started for App Distribution.**

Comment: Is there any other way to update the signedApk file path without using firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Update your `fastfile` with the below code, So it will take the latest release aab file from the given path and it will upload the same on the internal app sharing.

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
 desc 'Build a signed release APK & deploy to Internal App Sharing'
 lane :sign_apk_build do
   gradle(
     task: 'bundle',
     build_type: 'Release',
     print_command: false,
     properties: {
       'android.injected.signing.store.file' => ENV['storeFile'],
       'android.injected.signing.store.password' => ENV['storePassword'],
       'android.injected.signing.key.alias' => ENV['keyAlias'],
       'android.injected.signing.key.password' => ENV['keyPassword']
     }
   )
   upload_to_play_store_internal_app_sharing(
     aab: '/Users/dhavalkansara/Flutter Development/OfficeProjects/my-doses/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab' 
   )
 end
end
```

**Note:** You guys can update the aab path as per your project folder structure.